# What applescript commands can be sent to iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, applescript

I know you can tell the iOS Simulator to quit with applescript.  Can you tell it to go "home" from the current app?  And then click on the app's icon to relaunch it?  This would be useful for me for Application Tests that need to verify background tasks complete and numerous other cases.

Comment: You can tell it to do what ever you want, wether or not it listens is a whole different story. Really though good question, I'd like to know this myself. +1

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle - Just a little curious: what do you mean by "You can tell it to do what ever you want"? I'm not arguing against it, but wondering what you mean by that.

Comment: @qegal I've only used AppleScript enough to be aware that "tell" is a command, and I just thought of "tell" in terms of personification for the first time, like you can physically tell someone to do something but they might not listen. Chuckled to myself a little!

Answer (score 2):

Any AppleScriptable app must export a scripting dictionary in order for AppleScript to know what its commands are. You can see any app's dictionary by opening the app in Script Editor.

Note that even if an app doesn't provide script commands for what you want, System UI Scripting or Automator can likely still be used to drive its UI. (For example, to choose the Home or Rotate commands in iOS Simulator's menu bar.)

There's also iOS-specific UI automation stuff you can do from the Instruments app that comes with Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

The iOS Simulator does not directly support AppleScript.  It doesn't have a scripting dictionary.  This means that the only real way to manipulate it in AppleScript is to use the UI commands that work for any application.